# Is there a way in Mentor Graphics (Siemens) Pads Designer VX2.2 / Pads PCB to route through unused pads without generating a DRC error?

Tags: pcb-design, cad, mentor-pads, emmc

I am using an eMMC memory in one of my designs.  It is in a 153 ball package (which appears to be one of two industry standard packages for this type of memory).  The pads for the BGA balls have 0.33mm diameter (13.2 mils) and 0.5mm pitch.  That leaves 0.17mm (6.8 mils) spacing between each pad.

[image]

[(Image from Micron.com)](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/emmc/automotive/auto_emmc_8-128gb_1_8v_5_1.pdf)

To route traces between the pads spaced 6.8 mils apart would require like 2 mil traces with 2 mil spaces.  We are using 1/2 oz copper thickness on the outer layer.  I am not aware of any board houses that can reliably do 2 mil traces and spaces on 1/2 oz copper.  Normally they won't go below 4 mil traces / 4 mil spaces.  So, given that, we can't route between the balls.

If we can't route between the balls, the next option is drop vias-in-pad to do the breakout.  Our board has like 18 layers, so its 100 mils thick.  Typically, we wouldn't want vias smaller than 10 mils finished hole size on a 100 mil board.  We prefer to make our boards IPC Class 3, but even if we relaxed it to IPC Class 2 we would still be looking at a 20 mil pad for a 10 mil via.  But 20 mils is way larger than the 13.2-mil SMD pads, so that's out of the question.  To make this work we could potentially increase the pad size by 2.8 mils (making them exactly 15 mil diameter with 4 mil spacing), and then use 6-mil vias with 15 mil pads.  But doing 6-mil vias on a 100 mil thick board is usually not possible unless we are doing blind vias to layer 2 or 3 ( which is going to start increasing cost a lot).

So finally I came across Micron Technology [TN-FC-35 e.MMC PCB Design Guide](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/emmc/tnfc35_emmc_pcb_design_guide.pdf?), which has some advice for routing out of this package.  This chip has a lot of unused balls on the package.  Thier solution is basically to route straight through the unconnected balls on the top layer without using any vias.

[image]

From a physical standpoint that's fine.  But from a CAD standpoint its bad because, it will generate all kinds of DRC errors in our layout tool.  We are using Mentor Graphics (Now Siemens) Pads Designer VX2.2, and Pads Layout.  The only way I know of to avoid the errors would be to include a bunch of the NC balls on the schematic symbol, and then actually connect them in the schematic.

Including the NC balls is doable, and for now that's our plan, honestly I don't want to clutter up an
otherwise-clean schematic symbol with a bunch of unused balls.  **Is there a way to route through an unused SMD pad in Pads Designer without generating a DRC error?**

- Perhaps an attribute we could put on the pin or something?
- Maybe associating multiple SMD pads with one pin on the schematic symbol?  It forces a certain layout path, but at least it looks clean.
- Some other good way to breakout the signals on this type of memory that avoids the routing-through-unused-pads problem entirely?

Comment: Why not use vias to inner layers?

Comment: @Andyaka It's a good suggestion.  We were considering using blind vias to either layer 2 or 3, but I was hoping to avoid it because of the cost increase from additional PWB fabrication steps.  Honestly, I would also consider just switching to the 100 ball BGA package, which has wider pitch, except that we already bought a bunch of the eMMC memories for fear of them going out of stock (and in fact they are out of stock now).

Comment: Why use blind vias? Are you hampered on the other side of the PCB by something?

Comment: @Andyaka "Why use blind vias?"  The issue is the aspect ratio (length / drill-diameter) of the vias.  Typically, one doesn't want that to be greater than 10:1.  It's hard to reliably drill very long thin holes.  For a 100-mil thick board that limits us to vias with 10 mil drills or larger.  But to fit in the pads we would need 6 mil vias, which puts us at 16:1 aspect ratio, which most board houses won't do.  For a blind-via, they are just going part way through the board, probably < 20 mils length, which gives a 6-mil blind-via an aspect ratio of like 3:1, which is no problem.

Comment: I am beginning to believe that the 153 ball eMMC package was designed to work on a 0.060" thick board with 1/4 oz copper weight on the outer layers.  In that case there would be very few problems.